# What has corruptrwdcfs this puzzle?

Tags: cipher

I was working on a very simple puzzle late last night whem I fell asleep at the keyboard.
I awoke this morninf to find that somehow, my puzzle had been corrupted!
I was, of course, very disappointed that such a thing had happened, until I wracked my memory for what the initial puzzl was going to be.
Suddenly - it all became clear! My puzzle hadn't fallen vidtim to some malicious blip in my word professor, it had been made unreadable due to something else entirely - which, strangelu enough, was very thematic to the initial puzzle anyway, and is a bad habit I need to get on top of.

Because of this, I've decided to oresent my puzzle in its corrupted form. Your final answer will tell you what corrupted my puzzle! (4,3)

> zqwmhbszwthyfedwqsjnk
>   njkuokedaxedkojjmb
>   kopsrdrygsdweftawd
>   fyrlip
>   axzrsdwrs
>   knj
>   dfvtedeftrygukobcfrsd
>   guywsquokyrf

(Only the yellow text is needed to solve the puzzle, but the flavour text could prove very helpful. I have already read what not to do for a cipher puzzle :) I am of the full belief that this is a fun and approachable puzzle, and I HATE ciphers.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like:

> Every letter was replaced by three surrounding letters on the keyboard.

The original message then reads:

> anagram missin leters to see m crrtive hait

meaning

> We need to find the missing letters in that message, they are:
>  anagram missin**g** let**t**ers to see m**y** c**o**rr**up**tive ha**b**it

which leads to:

> **TYPO BUG**, an anagram of gtyoupb

Comment: Missed a line in the puzzle, sorry! It's been put back in the last edit, hopefully makes this step a bit easier.

Comment: The final answer is very thematic :)

Comment: Ah, so I guess, apply the same transformation again, hmm..

Comment: Nothing so convoluted, I added the enumeration of the answer which hopefully makes the anagramming easier!

Answer (score 3):

About the wrongly spelled words in the (normal) text:
In the title:

> Corruptrwdcfs -> Corrupted (e)

And in the text itself:

> Whem -> When (n)
>  Morninf -> Morning (g)
>  Puzzl -> Puzzle (e)
>  Vidtim -> Victim (c)
>  Blip -> Slip? (s?)
>  Strangelu -> Strangely (y)
>  oresent -> present (p)

Which leads to, if put together:

> engecsyp

Comment: Oh, looks like Levieux is on another track. Whoops!

Comment: OP said that only yellow text is needed, so I guess you're working on a red herring.

Comment: You are right. Nicely found @Levieux, you were too quick..

Comment: Btw, you missed professor (processor)

Comment: The typos were there to give a general idea of how the 'cipher' works. Early feedback on this puzzle was that there was no motivation to consider a keyboard at all, so I put typos in the plaintext as a bit of a push in the right direction! I suppose I could have hidden a little Easter egg message, but the thought didn't cross my mind at the time.

Comment: I completely missed the yellow text and immediately started to sum up the typos. That wasn't necessary after all... let's call it a nice distraction. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I made it to the last step:

> gtyoupb
>  
>  which is supposedly an anagram

but I'm terrible with them, so I repeated the same un-corrupting method and...

> gtyb --> h
>  
>  oup --> i
>  
>  result: "hi"

which doesn't follow exactly the same rules, but I thought the result was entertaining enough that it might be worth mentioning.